# 1500px by 2633px (5x9) image at 300dpi does not print 5 inches wide

Tags: c#, debugging, scaling, dpi, zebra-printers

**Summary**

My colleague is saving an image created from a report at 300dpi and trying to print this image to a Zebra ZT420 300dpi printer. The ribbon/media in the printer is 5 inches wide always but the length (height) can change. When he goes to print the image it is vastly enlarged on the printout and missing most of the image. How can this be printed properly since the printer is 300dpi by default and so is the image.

**Attempts**

He has tried this code he found online. Interesting is if he hardcodes m.Width to 341 it prints 5 inches wide but the image looks scaled or less quality than it should. The e.PageBounds by default are Width (500) and Height (600) which could be wrong and I assume they are being pulled from the printer driver settings.

```
        System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"C:\myimage.jpg");

        //Adjust the size of the image to the page to print the full image without loosing any part of it
        Rectangle m = e.PageBounds;

        if ((double)img.Width / (double)img.Height > (double)m.Width / (double)m.Height) // image is wider
        {
            m.Height = (int)((double)img.Height / (double)img.Width * (double)m.Width);
        }
        else
        {
            m.Width = (int)((double)img.Width / (double)img.Height * (double)m.Height);
        }
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, m);
```

**Expected Behavior**

Any images generated at 300dpi should be able to print properly on this 5 inch wide media. The width is fixed (1500px aka 5 inches) but the height will vary between (2633px aka 9 inches) and a little longer from time to time.

Comment: Somebody sold you a bridge in New York.  It is a 203 dpi resolution printer: https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra_new_ia/en-us/solutions-verticals/product/Printers/Industrial%20Printers/ZT400%20Series%20Industrial%20Printers/ZT420%20Industrial%20Printer/tech-specs/zt420-tech-specs-en-us.pdf

Comment: @HansPassant, if you look at page 2 of the product brief you linked to, you'll notice that there is an optional print head with 300 dpi resolution available for the Z420... ;-)

Comment: If you want to check whether the width of the image is larger than that of the page, you should perhaps not compare aspect ratios, but rather directly the widths of both image and page, no? Comparing aspect ratio cannot help you reliably determine whether width is larger or not; unless you also compare and account for the height that also contributes to an aspect ratio -- but which would be rather pointless, since you can just compare widths. (An aspect ratio value does not indicate a certain width whatsoever, it only expresses a relationship between width and height)

Comment: I don't really understand why you use e.PageBounds in this code. Or what DrawImage() overload you used, there isn't one that takes a Size. Use the Rectangle overload so you fully control the printed size. Default mapping is 100 pixels per inch so the Rectangle's  Width should be 500 to get 5 inches on the printer.  Which, if the printing head is indeed 300dpi, should map one pixel in the bitmap to exactly one dot on paper.